# Simple onclick event not triggering on Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, onclick

I have some simple HTML displaying a calendar as below. Once rendered the calendar has either 5 or 6 rows relative to the number of days in the month and which day of the week the 1st of the month is. Each day cell is clickable to execute some javascript. This all works fine on all desktop browsers and on iOS. However, with all versions of Android tested the bottom row of cells do not trigger the onclick event when clicked. Any ideas?

```
<div id="cal">
<div id="cal-caption">
    <span id="cal-last"><img src="/assets/images/arrow-left.png"></span>
    <span id="cal-month">May 2021</span>
    <span id="cal-next"><img src="/assets/images/arrow-right.png"></span>
</div>
<div id="cal-header">
<div class="cal-head">MON</div>
<div class="cal-head">TUE</div>
<div class="cal-head">WED</div>
<div class="cal-head">THU</div>
<div class="cal-head">FRI</div>
<div class="cal-head">SAT</div>
<div class="cal-head">SUN</div>
</div>
<div id="cal-body">
<div class="cal-row">
<div id="cl00" onclick="cal.click('cl00')"></div>
<div id="cl01" onclick="cal.click('cl01')"></div>
<div id="cl02" onclick="cal.click('cl02')"></div>
<div id="cl03" onclick="cal.click('cl03')"></div>
<div id="cl04" onclick="cal.click('cl04')"></div>
<div id="cl05" onclick="cal.click('cl05')"></div>
<div id="cl06" onclick="cal.click('cl06')"></div>
</div>
<div class="cal-row">
<div id="cl10" onclick="cal.click('cl10')"></div>
<div id="cl11" onclick="cal.click('cl11')"></div>
<div id="cl12" onclick="cal.click('cl12')"></div>
<div id="cl13" onclick="cal.click('cl13')"></div>
<div id="cl14" onclick="cal.click('cl14')"></div>
<div id="cl15" onclick="cal.click('cl15')"></div>
<div id="cl16" onclick="cal.click('cl16')"></div>
</div>
<div class="cal-row">
<div id="cl20" onclick="cal.click('cl20')"></div>
<div id="cl21" onclick="cal.click('cl21')"></div>
<div id="cl22" onclick="cal.click('cl22')"></div>
<div id="cl23" onclick="cal.click('cl23')"></div>
<div id="cl24" onclick="cal.click('cl24')"></div>
<div id="cl25" onclick="cal.click('cl25')"></div>
<div id="cl26" onclick="cal.click('cl26')"></div>
</div>
<div class="cal-row">
<div id="cl30" onclick="cal.click('cl30')"></div>
<div id="cl31" onclick="cal.click('cl31')"></div>
<div id="cl32" onclick="cal.click('cl32')"></div>
<div id="cl33" onclick="cal.click('cl33')"></div>
<div id="cl34" onclick="cal.click('cl34')"></div>
<div id="cl35" onclick="cal.click('cl35')"></div>
<div id="cl36" onclick="cal.click('cl36')"></div>
</div>
<div class="cal-row">
<div id="cl40" onclick="cal.click('cl40')"></div>
<div id="cl41" onclick="cal.click('cl41')"></div>
<div id="cl42" onclick="cal.click('cl42')"></div>
<div id="cl43" onclick="cal.click('cl43')"></div>
<div id="cl44" onclick="cal.click('cl44')"></div>
<div id="cl45" onclick="cal.click('cl45')"></div>
<div id="cl46" onclick="cal.click('cl46')"></div>
</div>
<div id="cal-extra" class="cal-row">
<div id="cl50" onclick="cal.click('cl50')"></div>
<div id="cl51" onclick="cal.click('cl51')"></div>
<div id="cl52" onclick="cal.click('cl52')"></div>
<div id="cl53" onclick="cal.click('cl53')"></div>
<div id="cl54" onclick="cal.click('cl54')"></div>
<div id="cl55" onclick="cal.click('cl55')"></div>
<div id="cl56" onclick="cal.click('cl56')"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="cal-footer">
<div class="cal-foot"></div>
<div class="cal-foot"></div>
<div class="cal-foot"></div>
<div class="cal-foot"></div>
<div class="cal-foot"></div>
<div class="cal-foot"></div>
<div class="cal-foot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "tested the bottom row of cells", do you mean it happens for some of the HTML elements at the bottom? Any invisible HTML elements that could overlap your rows when the screen becomes smaller?

Comment: Yes always the bottom row, so row 5 if no row 6 or row 6 and 5 works. Good shout regarding the overlap. Its responsive (bootstrap) so I will look into that - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is part of a bootstrap responsive layout. The issue only occurs in Chrome, when the viewport is narrow (phone sized). The calendar sits in the left hand 6 columns, with some text in the right 6 columns. As the page cascades and the viewport narrows the right hand 6 columns drop below the left hand columns but crucially in Chrome there is an overlap. The overlap is obscuring the bottom row of the calendar. To solve the issue I added a high z-index to the left hand columns and a low z-index to the right. So now the overlap still occurs but the calendar is on top and still clickable. Many thanks to T.Trassoudaine for pointing me in the right direction.